# How to profile a Jetty application in a Netbeans Maven Web Project?

Tags: netbeans, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to use Jetty in a Netbeans Maven Web Project (instead of Glassfish or Tomcat). I've managed to get running and debugging to work as follows:

1. Add the plugin to pom.xml:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
     <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>7.4.4.v20110707</version>
     <configuration>
       <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Project Properties -> Run -> Server -> `<No Server Selected>`
3. Project Properties -> Actions -> Run Project -> Goals = `jetty:run`
4. Project Properties -> Actions -> Debug Project -> Goals = `jetty:run`, add `jpda.listen=maven` to Set Properties

Any ideas on how to get the "Profile Project" action to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this isn't supported yet: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200771